# Blank/Black App launcher icon on Nougat, Oreo and Pie

Tags: android, android-layout, icons

I'm developing app in Xamarin.Android. Which currently supports Kitkat to Android P. Problem is that my app icon is showing fine on all other android version devices except Nougat, Oreo And Android P.

Android P ScreenShot

[image]

I'm using following link to generate android assets: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

App icon sample (transparent, mipmap-xxxhdpi, 192X192) launcher.png

[image]

Please help me here. Are there any special guidelines need follow on API 25+ for launcher icon ??. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are having has something to do with your launcher icons resources, without all the code is difficult to tell what is the cause.

If you want to create a launcher icon with support for all Android versions, you can create your app icon using Android Studio build in `Image Asset Studio`.

> Right-click the res folder and select New > Image Asset.

[image]

Documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio).

Comment: thanks for reply, Problem is that i'm developing app on Visual Studio Xamarin Android. Which don't have inbuilt Image Asset Studio. Just to create Launcher icons installing Whole Android studio is bit of stretch. Thanks anyway !!

Comment: I think at this point your way is only way to do it properly. Hope Visual Studio launches their own asset manager.